# How to extract a value from JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have the following json array.

```
[
"bucketName=myBucket",
]
```

It exists in a separate json file called parameters.json. It is the only thing in the file.

I have a bash script that is trying to extract the value "myBucket" from this json file with the following command:

```
jq '.bucketName' parameters.json
```

I am getting the following error:

```
jq: error (at parameters.json:3): Cannot index array with string "bucketName"
```

How can extract the value myBucket?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a key named `bucketName`; you have a string that can be *decoded* as a key/value pair.

```
$ jq '.[] | split("=") | select(.[0]=="bucketName")[1]' <<< '["bucketName=myBucket", "a=b"]
"myBucket"
```